# How to use Firestore realtime updates (onSnapshot) with redux-observable/rxjs?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, redux-observable

I am able to setup redux-observable with normal Firestore queries

```
export const getStatementsEpic = (action$, store) => {
  return action$.ofType(GET_STATEMENTS)
    .filter(() => {
      const state = store.getState()
      return state.auth.user
    })
    .mergeMap(() => {
      console.log('action', store.getState().auth.user.uid)
      const db = firebase.firestore()
      db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })
      const query = db.collection('users')
        .doc(store.getState().auth.user.uid)
        .collection('statements')
        .orderBy('uploadedOn', 'desc')
        .limit(50)
      return query.get().then(snapshot => {
        console.log('Should have gotten snapshot')
        return getStatementsSnapshot(snapshot)
      })
    })
}
```

But I want to convert this to be realtime, I tried changing

```
return query.get().then(snapshot => {
```

to

```
return query.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
```

But it does not work ... I guess this is not a promise? How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

You're correct, the `onSnapshot` method does not return a promise. Instead, it returns a function that can be used to *unsubscribe* from change notifications. Until that unsubscribe function is invoked, the callback passed to the `onSnapshot` method will be called every time the document changes. (The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/listen) indicates the callback will also be called immediately with the current document contents.)

Functions like `onSnapshot` that use a callback function multiple times can be "converted" into an observable using the `fromEventPattern` function. `fromEventPattern` takes two functions as parameters. The first function you pass needs to call `onSnapshot`, passing it a RxJS-defined handler as the callback. The second function you pass needs to call the unsubscribe function returned by `onSnapshot`. RxJS will call the first function when you subscribe to the observable (i.e. use it in your epic). RxJS will call the second function when you unsubscribe from the observable.

Here's an example of your code updated to use `fromEventPattern` and the new RxJS pipes:

```js
export const getStatementsEpic = (action$, state$) => action$.pipe(
  ofType(GET_STATEMENTS),
  withLatestFrom(state$),
  filter(([action, state]) => state.auth.user),
  mergeMap(([action, state]) => {
    const db = firebase.firestore()
    db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })
    return fromEventPattern(
      handler => db.collection('users')
        .doc(state.auth.user.uid)
        .collection('statements')
        .orderBy('uploadedOn', 'desc')
        .limit(50)
        .onSnapshot(handler),
      (handler, unsubscribe) => unsubscribe(),
    ).pipe(
      map(getStatementsSnapshot),
      takeUntil(action$.pipe(
        ofType(STOP_GET_STATEMENTS),
      )),
    )
  }),
)
```

Take note that I've introduced `takeUntil` to the snapshot stream. Without it (or something like it), the snapshot stream will never end. Another possible change is using `switchMap` instead of `mergeMap`. How to unsubscribe just depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little bit late, but the easiest way is to create `Observable` rather than using `fromEventPattern` since firebase event listener model were similar with rxjs Teardown model.

Here's the modified version using `Observable` constructor.

```
export const getStatementsEpic = (action$, store) => {
  return action$.ofType(GET_STATEMENTS)
    .filter(() => {
      const state = store.getState()
      return state.auth.user
    })
    .mergeMap(() => {
      console.log('action', store.getState().auth.user.uid)
      const db = firebase.firestore()
      db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })
      return new Observable(subscriber => db.collection('users')
        .doc(state.auth.user.uid)
        .collection('statements')
        .orderBy('uploadedOn', 'desc')
        .limit(50)
        .onSnapshot(subscriber.next, subscriber.error)
      );
    })
}
```